# highchart y-axis range 0-100 200 300 after 1k 2k and 3k

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have tried to change the y-axis value in highchart, data containing the count from 0 to 3000, 0 count records are not visible if i reduced the

y-axis max:150

chart does not suites, is this possible to set y-axis stating from 0-100 200 300... after 1k it should show 2k 3k....

```
yAxis: {
                    min: 0, max: 3000,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Number of Items'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tickPositions and formatter for labels:

```
yAxis: {
  tickPositions: [0, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 3000],
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
      if (this.value < 1000) {
        return this.value
      }
      return this.value / 1000 + 'k'
    }
  }
},
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o9he6zLx/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositions